# Overridding default sender ActionMailer Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

As being completely new to Rails, I have one question related to action mailer. In my setup_email.rb in /config/initializer/setup_email.rb, I have email configuration like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
 :port                 => 587,  
 :domain               => "yoolk.com",  
 :user_name            => "yoolkers",  
 :password             => "secrete",  
 :authentication       => "plain",  
 :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

Also in my /app/mailers/contact_us_mailer.rb, I got some code:

```
class ContactUsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'abc@yoolk.com'
  def send_email 
    mail(:to => 'victory@yoolk.com', :subject => 'Test Action Mailer')  
  end  
end
```

When I called send_email method in my controller, it worked fine, email sent to victory@yoolk.com. However, the sender was yoolkers@gmail.com. What I really want is sender as abc@yoolk.com. I have been looking through for this for days, but I couldn't find any solution at all. Is there any way to change the default sender from the configuration email? I would appreciate for your contribute.

Thanks

Comment: any luck with this? i'm having a similar problem.

Comment: Yes I got it done, sorry I forgot to post the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991932/sending-confirmation-emails-to-registered-users-in-ror-app-via-localhost/10994387#10994387