# Error when sending email confirmation using ActionMailer on ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, confirmation-email

I am developing a website using ROR on Windows 7 (64-bit). I am trying to setup my website so that a person who creates a new login on it gets a confirmation email. I am using ActionMailer for the email confirmation sending. I am trying to configure it to send confirmation email using Gmail SMTP server. (This is just for testing. Once it works, I can use something else on the deployment server.)

I am getting this error:

```
   Application-specific password required
```

Here is the code snippet from development.rb:

```
        config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
        config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

        # these options are only needed if you choose smtp delivery
       config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
       :port           => 587,
       :domain         => 'gmail.com',
       :authentication => :login,
       :user_name      => 'my_login@gmail.com',
       :password       => 'my_application_specific_password'
       }
```

Why I am getting this error even though I generated a new application-specific password for this purpose and am using it? How to fix this?

Comment: Your question looks quite similar to this:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991932/sending-confirmation-emails-to-registered-users-in-ror-app-via-localhost/10994387#10994387

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have enabled extra 2-step security on the Google Account you are using to send emails. This can require you to sign in using a special code sent to your mobile phone by text message; or for particular non-compatible applications, creating an 'Application-specific password'.

More details on Application-specific passwords [here](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833).

Comment: Thanks Rob! I have 2-factor authentication enabled on my Google account. But, I have generated an application specific password and that is what I am using in the configuration above. Any idea what else might be going wrong?

Comment: Hm... Have you tried changing `:authentication => :login` to `:authentication => :plain`?